# Oracle SQL query: Split string by space and get the nth string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been searching this all over on stackoverflow and haven't able to find the answer yet.

Given String "hello my name is...", I would like to split the string by spaces and get the nth element of that string.

For example, after splitting: [hello, my, name, is...]
the 1st element is "hello", 2nd element is "my", so on..

My attempt:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(help, ' ', 1, 2) from 
(select 'hello my name is...' as help from dual);
```

This is incorrect giving me an empty result. I think something wrong with the regex space.

Comment: First: If you have two consecutive spaces, will you consider that as an element (the element being the *empty string*, which Oracle treats the same as `null`)? Or do you want one, two or any number of consecutive spaces to be considered as a **single** separator? Second: what if the input string has fewer than n elements? What do you want to show in the output?

Comment: Only single space. Assume input r always single space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pretty close.  You just need to search for *non-spaces*, because that is what you want to return:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(help, '[^ ]+', 1, 2)
from (select 'hello my name is...' as help from dual);
```